# When is $a \space \sin^2(x) + b \space \cos^2(x) \le 1$?

Tags: trigonometry

When is the above expression less than or equal to $1$, meaning for what values of $a$ and $b$ will the above expression be less than or equal to $1$?

Comment: Do you mean for what values of $a$ and $b$ will it be less than or equal to $1$ for all $x$? For that, suppose for the moment that $a \leq b$, then $a \sin^2(x)+b\cos^2(x)=a \sin^2(x)+a \cos^2(x)+(b-a)\cos^2(x)=a+(b-a) \cos^2(x)$. Since $\cos^2(x)$ maxes out at $1$, the max of this is $b$. Now do it with $a > b$ (the situation is basically the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, clearly it equals 1 when $a=b=1$. Rewrite $b=a+c$. Then you are asking when

$$a\sin^2 x+b\cos^2x=a\sin^2x+(a+c)\cos^2x=a(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)+c\cos^2x=a+c\cos^2x>1$$

or when

$$\cos^2x>\frac{1-a}{c}=\frac{1-a}{b-a}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint
$$a\sin^2{x}+b\cos^2{x}=a+(b-1)\cos^2{x}$$
and Note
$$0\le \cos^2{x}\le 1$$